# how to write a regular expression for a url to create a google analytics destination goal?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to create a destination goal in google analytics. The URL is -https://www.dropbox.com/sh/afxvoo7yramakbj/AADdI77nqKL2sT5mIYXxYlyya?dl=0

This part https://www.dropbox.com/sh/  is same in all destination but the later characters vary. what do I need to write to create a regular expression.
Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks for reading this. Hope you guys have a great day.

with Regards,
Bhola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm tempted to say that you should use the wildcard match to match anything and everything after the `sh/` like this

```
^/sh/.*
```

but this might be too broad for you. But then again that stuff after the `sh/` looks too random to find a pattern. If the random stuff is always in this format

`https://www.dropbox.com/sh/random_thing/another_random_thing?dl=0`

then you could try this pattern

```
^/sh/.*/.*\?dl=0
```

Not sure if the query parameter changes either, but you should try to learn a bit of regex to figure that part out if the pattern doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, dear for the help. Hope you have a great day ahead.